How do I make my gameOver function in Javascript jQuery work?
I'm new to JS and I'mm doing a project but I keep having trouble with the feature that resets the game when you fail. When you press the wrong button in a memorizing game, it will reset but then the game breaks.


//varibles
const buttonColors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow'];
let gamePattern = [];

let userClickedPattern = [];
let userChosenColor;

let level = 0;
let started = false;

function playSound(name) {
  let sound = new Audio('./sounds/' + name + '.mp3');
  sound.play();
}

function gameOver() {
  playSound('wrong');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('body').removeClass('game-over');
  }, 500);
  $('#level-title').text('Game Over, Press Any Key to Restart');
  $('body').addClass('game-over');

  started = false;
  level = 0;
  gamePattern = [];
}

//get a sequence
function nextSequence() {
  userClickedPattern = [];
  level++;
  $('#level-title').text('Level ' + level);

  let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  let randomColor = buttonColors[randomNumber];
  gamePattern.push(randomColor);

  for (let i = 0; i < gamePattern.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#' + gamePattern[i]).animate({
        opacity: 0.25
      }, 100);
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('#' + gamePattern[i]).animate({
          opacity: 1
        }, 100);
      }, 25);

      playSound(gamePattern[i]);
    }, (500 * (i + 1)));
  }
}

//get the user sequence stuff
function animatePress(currentColor) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#' + currentColor).removeClass('pressed');
  }, 100);
  $('#' + currentColor).addClass('pressed');
}

function userSequence() {
  $('.btn').click(function() {
    userChosenColor = $(this).attr('id');
    userClickedPattern.push(userChosenColor);

    animatePress(userChosenColor);
    playSound(userChosenColor);

    checkAnswer(userClickedPattern.length);
  });
}

//check if answer is right or wrong
function checkAnswer(currentLevel) {
  // let rightCounter = 0;
  // if (gamePattern.length == currentLevel) {
  //   for (let i = 0; i < gamePattern.length; i++) {
  //     if (gamePattern[i] == userClickedPattern[i]) {
  //       rightCounter++;
  //     } else {gameOver();}
  //   }
  //   if (rightCounter == gamePattern.length) {
  //     setTimeout(function () {
  //       userClickedPattern = [];
  //       nextSequence();
  //     }, 500);
  //   } else {gameOver();}
  // }
  if (gamePattern[currentLevel - 1] == userClickedPattern[currentLevel - 1]) {
    if (gamePattern.length == currentLevel) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        nextSequence();
      }, 500);
    }
  } else {
    gameOver();
  }
}

//start game
function startGame() {
  nextSequence();
  userSequence();
}

//start game
$('body').keydown(function() {
  if (started == false) {
    startGame();
    started = true;
  }
});
body {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #011F3F;
}

#level-title {
  font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin: 5%;
  color: #FEF2BF;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}

.btn {
  margin: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  border-radius: 20%;
}

.game-over {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.pressed {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px white;
  background-color: grey;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Simon</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Press+Start+2P" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="level-title">Press Any Key to Start</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div lass="row">

      <div type="button" id="green" class="btn green">

      </div>

      <div type="button" id="red" class="btn red">

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

      <div type="button" id="yellow" class="btn yellow">

      </div>
      <div type="button" id="blue" class="btn blue">

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./game.js"></script>
</body>

</html>



I've asked chatGPT but it always gave me advanced stuff that I didn't know what it did and I'd like to understand my code so if I ever come across a similar problem, I can solve it. When you press the wrong button (div element), it goes into game over, but in a glitched version. Anytime you click something, it will always be wrong even if it's the right one. I'd like it to act normally.

what does but in a glitched version and I'd like it to act normally even mean?

basiclly, when you get game over, then when the game restarts, it just glitches and any button you press will cause another gameover even if its the right button. by 'acting noramally', i'd like it to not do that glitch and instead let it be like if you first started it before it glitched.

note: every time you call userSequence you're adding click event handlers to the "buttons" ... you end up with userClickedPattern having multiple entries for a single button click

And you call userSequence() each time you call startGame(), which explains why the second and subsequent games are glitchy.

I took a look, and here are the observations I've made.
First, I checked the value of your victory condition when gameOver(); is called in checkAnswer();.
console.log("gamePattern ", gamePattern[currentLevel - 1])
console.log("userClickedPattern ", userClickedPattern[currentLevel - 1])
gameOver();

In the first iteration of your game, everything works fine, but there is indeed an issue starting from the second iteration, that is, after the first Game Over. From then on, your gamePattern becomes undefined. However, if I log in your nextSequence(); function, gamePattern is defined.
It seems the issue originates elsewhere. As @JaromandaX and @Barmar explained, you call userSequence(); at the start of each game, which results in multiple entries for a single button click.
How to avoid this? You currently have two solutions:
Ensure that userSequence(); is only called once
Remove previous entries when userSequence(); is called again
For the first solution, you can simply do:
//start game
function startGame() {
  nextSequence();
}

//start game
$('body').keydown(function() {
    if (started == false) {
        startGame();
        started = true;
    }
});
userSequence();

For the second, we’ll use off()
This way, $('.btn').click becomes $('.btn').off('click').click.
Which gives us:


const buttonColors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow'];
let gamePattern = [];

let userClickedPattern = [];
let userChosenColor;

let level = 0;
let started = false;

function playSound(name) {
  let sound = new Audio('./sounds/' + name + '.mp3');
  sound.play();
}

function gameOver() {
  playSound('wrong');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('body').removeClass('game-over');
  }, 500);
  $('#level-title').text('Game Over, Press Any Key to Restart');
  $('body').addClass('game-over');

  started = false;
  level = 0;
  gamePattern = [];
}

//get a sequence
function nextSequence() {
  userClickedPattern = [];
  level++;
  $('#level-title').text('Level ' + level);

  let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  let randomColor = buttonColors[randomNumber];
  gamePattern.push(randomColor);

  for (let i = 0; i < gamePattern.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#' + gamePattern[i]).animate({
        opacity: 0.25
      }, 100);
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('#' + gamePattern[i]).animate({
          opacity: 1
        }, 100);
      }, 25);

      playSound(gamePattern[i]);
    }, (500 * (i + 1)));
  }
}

//get the user sequence stuff
function animatePress(currentColor) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#' + currentColor).removeClass('pressed');
  }, 100);
  $('#' + currentColor).addClass('pressed');
}

function userSequence() {
  $('.btn').click(function() {
    userChosenColor = $(this).attr('id');
    userClickedPattern.push(userChosenColor);

    animatePress(userChosenColor);
    playSound(userChosenColor);

    checkAnswer(userClickedPattern.length);
  });
}

//check if answer is right or wrong
function checkAnswer(currentLevel) {
  // let rightCounter = 0;
  // if (gamePattern.length == currentLevel) {
  //   for (let i = 0; i < gamePattern.length; i++) {
  //     if (gamePattern[i] == userClickedPattern[i]) {
  //       rightCounter++;
  //     } else {gameOver();}
  //   }
  //   if (rightCounter == gamePattern.length) {
  //     setTimeout(function () {
  //       userClickedPattern = [];
  //       nextSequence();
  //     }, 500);
  //   } else {gameOver();}
  // }
  if (gamePattern[currentLevel - 1] == userClickedPattern[currentLevel - 1]) {
    if (gamePattern.length == currentLevel) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        nextSequence();
      }, 500);
    }
  } else {
    gameOver();
  }
}

//start game
function startGame() {
  nextSequence();
}

//start game
$('body').keydown(function() {
    if (started == false) {
    startGame();
    started = true;
}
});
userSequence(); // <-- Moved userSequence() here to fix the issue
body {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #011F3F;
}

#level-title {
  font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin: 5%;
  color: #FEF2BF;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}

.btn {
  margin: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  border-radius: 20%;
}

.game-over {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.pressed {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px white;
  background-color: grey;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Simon</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Press+Start+2P" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="level-title">Press Any Key to Start</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div lass="row">

      <div type="button" id="green" class="btn green">

      </div>

      <div type="button" id="red" class="btn red">

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

      <div type="button" id="yellow" class="btn yellow">

      </div>
      <div type="button" id="blue" class="btn blue">

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./game.js"></script>
</body>

</html>



